# How to Unit Test utility class in ios Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing

I am new to Unit Testing. I have learned to create unit test for view controllers, UITableView and URL session. But in projects we usual have Utility class having functions like storing data in User Defaults, checking network, some other handy calculations etc. My question is should we Unit Test these kind of Utility Classes?
If yes how these unit test can be implemented?
Update: here's some of the functions in Utility class

```
 //MARK: Store/Retrive Wathclist symbol from persistent storage
    static func storeToPersistent(List: [String]){
        UserDefaults.standard.setValue(List, forKey: "WatchList")
    }
    
    static func getFromPersistent() -> [String]{
        if let arr = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "WatchList") as? [String]{
            return arr
        } else {
            return []
        }
    }
    
    //MARK: Internet availability
    static func isInternetAvailable() -> Bool {
        /// Sample Socket Address
        var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in()
        zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: zeroAddress))
        zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)
        
        /// Reachability status
        let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(to: &zeroAddress) {
            $0.withMemoryRebound(to: sockaddr.self, capacity: 1) { zeroSockAddress in
                SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, zeroSockAddress)
            }
        }
        
        /// Flags of Reachability
        var flags = SCNetworkReachabilityFlags()
        if !SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability!, &flags) {
            return false
        }
        
        /// Check Connectivity Flag
        let isReachable = flags.contains(.reachable)
        /// If needs a Conection
        let needsConnection = flags.contains(.connectionRequired)
        return (isReachable && !needsConnection)
    }
```

Comment: It is important to understand what we are testing, protocol seems like one way, but it would be better if you could provide a simple example so that we can look at ways to address it

Comment: Become really familiar with dependency injection. In fact, do some research on SOLID design principles: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID Make sure that your objects aren't tightly coupled with other objects or it becomes a nightmare.

Comment: Well, what is it that you want to test? Not SCNetworkReachability, obviously; we know what it does, and it is not ours to test. You want, presumably,  to test the _logic_ of your `isInternetAvailable` to see if, given certain inputs, it produces a certain output. To test that, first write the method in a testable way, such that it takes a parameter for which you can substitute your own mock version the SCNNetwork... stuff. Then, in your test, perform that substitution, with the mock being configurable to give the desired responses to your calls to it so that you can see what your method does.

Comment: Unit testing is generally about _fixtures_ and _mocks_ that hedge your methods in with something that _looks_ like the thing they would normally talk to, but is in fact _your_ thing so that you get to say what the inputs are. Keep your eye on the ball of what exactly is the "system under test", and make sure you test that and nothing else; whatever is not the actual "system under test" must be mocked. (I use the word mock loosely.)

Comment: `I have learned to create unit test for view controllers, UITableView and URL session.` this doesn't sounds right. For example URL session should be mocked not tested. Looks like you have a problem spotting what is your code and what is your dependency.

Comment: And in answer to your more general question: yes, you should unit test _everything_ that is your code. 100% test coverage is an impossible dream, but 80% is a reasonable minimum, and 90% is a typical real-life percentage. In my workplace, _every type_ that we declare, except ridiculously simple things like enums that are just a list of cases, or simple structs with no custom initializer, _must_ be accompanied by a suite of tests.

Comment: @matt i got the answer now. I need to refactor some of my utility functions in a way that can be tested. and then i can even test my utility class itself. Thanks !!